Some Cube solver using Python/SageMath
I'm new in SageMath/Python and I try to use the Tiling Solver.
I failed to retrieve the 240 expected solutions of the Soma Cube (see the Wikipedia page).
Here's what I've done so far:
from sage.combinat.tiling import TilingSolver, Polyomino
from sage.all_cmdline import *   # import sage library

P1 = Polyomino([(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0)], color='red')
P2 = Polyomino([(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,2,0)], color='red')
P3 = Polyomino([(0,0,0), (0,1,1), (0,1,0), (0,2,0)], color='red')
P4 = Polyomino([(0,0,1), (0,1,1), (0,1,0), (0,2,0)], color='red')
P5 = Polyomino([(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,1)], color='red')
P6 = Polyomino([(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,1)], color='red')
P7 = Polyomino([(0,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,0,0), (1,1,0)], color='red')


# G = P1.show3d()
# G.show(aspect_ratio=1, viewer='jmol')

T = TilingSolver([P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7], box=(3,3,3))
T.number_of_solutions()

T.number_of_solutions() #returns 15 504 instead of 240 ??

Perhaps some cube symetries are taken into account, but 15 504 / 240 = 64.6....
Do you have any ideas here?

Question answered here : https://ask.sagemath.org/question/80416/use-of-tiling-solver-for-the-soma-cube/
